# How to format LocalDateTime yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm to dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm as String for a whole list of an object which contains not only a date attribute?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, java-stream, datetimeformatter

I am trying to solve a problem which seems to be tricky on which I got stuck. Could you help please?

In Spring Boot I have an object `Holiday` for national holidays persisted on a MySQL database. The object `Holiday` contains the following attributes:

```
(...)

@Column(name = "title")
private String HolidayTitle;

@Column(name = "date")
private String holidayDate;

@Column(name = "updated")
private LocalDateTime updated;

@Column(name = "country")
private String country;

(...)
```

But I am interested on the `updated` attribute, which is stored, for example, as 2021-10-26 20:54:48 in the database. I want to format it as dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm to Thymeleaf, but it consists of a list of `Holiday` objects with different attributes.

In controller, the list is being retrieved as the following:

```
@GetMapping("/getAllHolidays")
public String getAllHolidays(Model theModel) {
    List<Holiday> theHolidays = holidayService.findAll();
    theModel.addAttribute("holidays", theHolidays);
    return "holidays";
}
```

How to format only the attribute *`updated`* for all holiday objects in the list *`theHolidays`* by using `DateTimeFormatter`?

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
```

Is it possible to achieve this by using Java stream?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to parse (=from string) or format (=to string)? What's the specific problem? And what does streams have to do with it?

Comment: Hi @shmosel sorry for the confusion. b.GHILAS below proposed a simple and functional solution. I needed to both parse from LocalDateTime to String and format it. Thank you for your response.

Comment: You can't parse from date to string. That's called formatting.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse the dates using Java Stream like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");

List<String> formattedDates = theHolidays.stream()
      .map(Holiday::getUpdated)
      .map(formatter::format)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But if you're using thymeleaf, you can format your dates like this:

```
<tr th:each="holiday : ${holidays}">
  <td th:text="${#temporals.format(holiday.updated, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm')}"></td>
</tr>
```